# How can stop sftp download and upload a specific file in the root user and cat command

Tags: centos

**how to stop sftp root user transfir and donload for specific file**

linux centos 7

I have a text file located in the root folder
But . I want to give someone a root user password and I need to protect my file. I want to make sure that this person cannot download this file to his device via sftp

and stop cat this file

Comment: You can't. If you give someone root access he has all privileges to remove your restrictions. Either you trust someone to give him root access or you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a text file located in the root folder ...

Probably not a Good Idea to start with.
Linux has conventions about where files *should* be placed.  The root directory is *not* one of them.

> But I want to give someone a root user password ...

Bad Idea.
Always keep the biggest and best tools in the toolbox for yourself, so that you can clean up the mess made by other people (and processes).
If you hand out the root password, you abandon *all control* of that server.

> ... and I need to protect my file.

You *cannot* have both.
Anyone with root access can do *anything*.  By design.

(What's *in* this oh-so-important file, anyway?)

Find another way to get this user the access that they require.
**sudo** is a common solution and it *doesn't* [have to] involve handing out root access!  (You can tell sudo to allow certain commands to run as a *specific* user, not just root).

> I want to make sure that this person cannot download this file to his device via sftp and stop cat this file

If you don't want them to be able to *look* at the file (through cat) and you don't want them to be able to *read* the file (to download it) what *do* you want them to be able to do with it?